# How to show PDF file in MigraDoc.Rendering.Forms.DocumentPreview (in WinForms)?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have a simple questions. How can you show a PDf file by using PagePreview?

I have a full pathname document.FileName = "c:\scans\Insurance_34345.pdf";

pagePreview.Preview(document.FileName); or something...

If there another way for showing a pdf. It's okay. I want to show it on a WinForms Form.

I tried this. I don't know what I have to do...

in the Designer

```
private MigraDoc.Rendering.Forms.DocumentPreview dpvScannedDoc;
```

Part of the code

```
                string fullPadnaam = Path.Combine(defaultPath, document.FileName);
                //PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(fullPadnaam);
                //PdfPage page = new PdfPage(pdfDocument);
                //XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
                MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document pdfDocument = new MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document();
                pdfDocument.ImagePath = fullPadnaam;

                 var docRenderer = new DocumentRenderer(pdfDocument);
                 docRenderer.PrepareDocument();

                 var inPdfDoc = PdfReader.Open(fullPadnaam, PdfDocumentOpenMode.ReadOnly);
                 for (var i = 0; i < inPdfDoc.PageCount; i++)
                 {
                     pdfDocument.AddSection();
                     docRenderer.PrepareDocument();

                     var page = inPdfDoc.Pages[i];

                     var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

                     docRenderer.RenderPage(gfx, i + 1);
                 }

                 var renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer();

                 renderer.Document = pdfDocument;

                 renderer.RenderDocument();

                // MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.IO.DdlWriter dw = new MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.IO.DdlWriter("HelloWorld.mdddl");
                // dw.WriteDocument(pdfDocument);
                // dw.Close();

                //renderer.PdfDocument.rea(outFilePath);
                //string ddl = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.IO.DdlWriter.WriteToString(document1);
                dpvScannedDoc.Show( pdfDocument);
```

Answer (score 0):

PDFsharp does not render PDF files. You cannot show PDF files using the `PagePreview`.

If you use the `XGraphics` class for drawing then you can use shared code that draws on the `PagePreview` and on PDF pages.

The PagePreview sample can be found in the sample package and here:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Preview-sample.ashx

If you have code that creates a new PDF file using PDFsharp then you can use the `PagePreview` to show on screen what you would otherwise draw on PDF pages. You cannot draw existing PDF pages using the `PagePreview` because PDF does not render PDF.

Comment: And how do you that? I can't find examples such like that? PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(document.FileName);
                PdfPage page = new PdfPage(pdfDocument);
                XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

Comment: I don't know how to go to the PagePreview with this code.

Comment: What you want cannot be done with PDFsharp because PDFsharp does not render PDF pages.

Answer (score 0):

The MigraDoc `DocumentPreview` can display MDDDL files (your sample code creates a file "HelloWorld.mdddl"), but it cannot display PDF files.

If the MDDDL uses PDF files as images, they will not show up in the preview. They will show when creating a PDF from the MDDDL.

Comment: That's just a copy of the internet. I just want to know how to show a pdf file on Windows Form. That's my question. Can you help me?

Comment: You cannot show PDF files with PDFsharp, you cannot show PDF files with MigraDoc. I cannot recommend tools that can display PDF files.